# R compare dates with group by statement

Tags: r, dplyr

Using dplyr, I want to do a group by, followed by a date comparison for the following data frame.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,6),
                 X1 = c("A","A","B","C","A","B","B","B","C","A"),
                 X2 = sample(10:30,10,replace = TRUE),
                 dat = as.Date(c("2021-01-01","2021-01-01","2021-02-01","2021-02-01","2021-01-03",
                         "2021-10-05","2021-05-05","2021-05-06","2021-09-14","2021-06-04")))
```

The group by should be on ID and X1 (X2 can be ignored). So basically, for all IDs with identical values for X1, the dates should be compared and IDs where the dates difference is 1 (positive or negative) or less should be kept. The desired output is:

```
  ID X1
1  1  A
2  1  A
3  4  B
4  4  B
```

Comment: What is meant by the date difference? Which dates are being compared?

Comment: For each combination of ID and X1 having more than 1 identical combination. So, ID 1 has 2 identical values for X1 (A). Therefore the dates shoud be compared. The same goes for ID 4. IDs 2,3,5,6 have distinct (or just 1) values for X1 and should therefore be excluded. That's why I was thinking of a group by, but maybe there is a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grouping by `ID` and `X1` select only those groups that have 2 or more rows and the difference between dates is 1.

You can try -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID, X1) %>%
  filter(n() >= 2, all(abs(diff(dat)) <= 1)) %>%
  ungroup

#     ID X1       X2 dat       
#  <dbl> <chr> <int> <date>    
#1     1 A        30 2021-01-01
#2     1 A        19 2021-01-01
#3     4 B        24 2021-05-05
#4     4 B        30 2021-05-06
```

If you are only interested in `ID` and `X1` column add `%>% select(ID, X1)`.